# why poetry is failing at installing a freshly released pypi package?

Tags: python-poetry

I want to install the freshly released version 2.4.0 of datasets (https://pypi.org/project/datasets/2.4.0/).

With pip, it works:

```
$ pip install datasets==2.4.0
```

With poetry, it fails:

```
$ poetry add datasets==2.4.0

  ValueError

  Could not find a matching version of package datasets
```

Comment: Note that the issue only lasts for some hours, afterward the package with the new version can be installed, of course. In my case, 2022-07-25T13:21:43+0000: datasets 2.4.0 has been released on pypi, 2022-07-25T16:16:01+0000, ie h+3: I add the issue, 2022-07-25T18:12:30+0000, ie h+5: the issue is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poetry uses PyPi's JSON Api to retrieve necessary metadata. They had some problem yesterday, which is fixed in the meantime. See https://github.com/pypi/warehouse/issues/11949

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue, what worked for me was to run:

```
poetry cache clear --all .
```

And then trying to install the freshly release version.